# How do I use lua keyword as a table key?

Tags: lua, lua-table, luajit

## Problem

When I use `do`, a lua keyword as a table's key it gives following error

```
> table.newKey = { do = 'test' }
stdin:1: unexpected symbol near 'do'
>
```

I need to use `do` as key. What should I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sometable.somekey` is syntactic sugar for `sometable['somekey']`,

similarly `{ somekey = somevalue }` is sugar for `{ ['somekey'] = somevalue }`

---

Information like this can be found in this very good resource:

> For such needs, there is another, more general, format. In this format, we explicitly write the index to be initialized as an expression, between square brackets:
>
> ```
> opnames = {["+"] = "add", ["-"] = "sub",
>            ["*"] = "mul", ["/"] = "div"}
> ```

-- [Programming in Lua: 3.6 – Table Constructors](https://www.lua.org/pil/3.6.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use this syntax:

```
t = { ['do'] = 'test' }
```

or `t['do']` to get or set a value.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to use do as key. What should I do ?

Read the Lua 5.4 Reference Manual and understand that something like `t = { a = b}` or `t.a = b` only works if `a` is a valid Lua identifier.

[3.4.9 - Table constructors](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.9)

> The general syntax for constructors is
>
> ```
> tableconstructor ::= ‘{’ [fieldlist] ‘}’
>
> fieldlist ::= field {fieldsep field} [fieldsep]
>
> field ::= ‘[’ exp ‘]’ ‘=’ exp | Name ‘=’ exp | exp
>
> fieldsep ::= ‘,’ | ‘;’
> ```

> A field of the form `name = exp` is equivalent to `["name"] = exp`.

So why does this not work for `do`?

[3.1 - Lexical Conventsions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.1)

> Names (also called identifiers) in Lua can be any string of Latin
> letters, Arabic-Indic digits, and underscores, not beginning with a
> digit and not being a reserved word. Identifiers are used to name
> variables, table fields, and labels.
>
> The following keywords are reserved and cannot be used as names:
>
> ```
>  and       break     do        else      elseif    end
>  false     for       function  goto      if        in
>  local     nil       not       or        repeat    return
> ```

`do` is not a *name* so you need to use the syntax `field ::= ‘[’ exp ‘]’ ‘=’ exp`

which in your example is `table.newKey = { ['do'] = 'test' }`